# Transform list in folders SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, list, folder

I am new at SharePoint Online and I have created a list of items about clients ex:

```
Name     Email      Note 
Alan    some mail   note...

Adam    some mail   note...
```

Is it possible that I transform this list in folders eg. folder Alan, Adam..

I am using SharePoint Online

Comment: It is simpler (ant from SP IA perspective better) to create or modify default view to group items by Name in your case.

Comment: Folders should be avoided in SharePoint.  Instead create a view, and group by columns.  In this case, as @martusha said, you want to group by `Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of folders because you are new to this.

What you are looking for is using content type. Create a content type named Client and add required properties to it. The add this content type to list.

Now you can create views respective to each business case.

If you go with folder approach it will cause issues down the line.